# Facebook Graph API: Cannot pass categories array on Python

Tags: python, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use Facebook's Graph API to get all the restaurants within a certain location. I'm doing this on Python and my url is

```
url ="https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=14.6091,121.0223,50000&categories=[\"FOOD_BEVERAGE\"]&fields=name,location,category,fan_count,rating_count,overall_star_rating&limit=100&access_token=" + access
```

However, this is the error message I get.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) For field 'placesearch': param categories must be an array.", 
    "code": 100, 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "fbtrace_id": "EGQ8YdwnzUT"
  }
}
```

But when I paste the URL on the Graph explorer (linked below), it works. I can't do this exhaustively on the explorer because I need to collect restaurant data from all the next pages. Can someone help me explain why this is happening and how to fix it so that I can access it through Python?

[Example Link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=search%3Ftype%3Dplace%26center%3D14.6091%2C121.0223%2C50000%26categories%3D[%22FOOD_BEVERAGE%22]%26fields%3Dname%2Clocation%2Ccategory%2Cfan_count%2Crating_count%2Coverall_star_rating%26limit%3D100%26access_token%3DEAACEdEose0cBALAXFo7ZCfNj6lni6JbVxiuzS0FJv9ElpgzimrGfkYZAJrnB4Pvc4Dr01TnfppZCUXrBrmb32R3BBTKNHU0uylvBd1PFMz3hUzOb3B2kiz3XOkYhL0AR368VbGWrTYsQPnzkLB9CerHdbMnVvkRsVu3ZCkvofAk5Po6etnZAgCmDESNYVq1gZD&version=v3.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify an API version, so this will fall back to the lowest version your app can use.

I can reproduce the error for API versions <= v2.8 in Graph API Explorer - for v2.9 and above it works.

So use `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/search?…` (at least, or a higher version, up to you.)

Comment: Fixed the problem by using the cURL that explorer gave instead, which had the API version. Thanks!